# Number of vertices of nth degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a general formula to determine the coordinates of the extrema of just the number of extrema of any $n^{th}$ degree polynomial? It's okay if you give me an algorithm or a recurrence but I prefer an equation as an answer instead of  the algorithm.

Comment: What are the "vertices" of a polynomial?

Comment: @GregMartin I would not say the extrema because we can have a very slight change and still call it an extremum, I would not also say the point where the derivative of the polynomial is zero because that would be in conflict with the linear function. I think the only thing that i could say is that it is the point where the derivative is zero and the derivative at the abscissa plus or minus an infinitesimally small number is positive or negative Example: The vertices of f(x)=(x-5)^4-2(x-5)^2 are (4, -1), (5, 0), and (6, -1).

Comment: The points you list *are* the extrema of that function.

Comment: @Jens Instead of vertices, I would say extrema

Comment: Calculating the extrema of any function $f(x)$ means that you have to solve the equation $\frac{df}{dx}=0$. If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $\frac{df}{dx}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. But: There are no formulas to calculate the roots of every polynomial of a fixed degree greater than 4. So the answer to your question is "no".